# "Can we use the same proxy_pass for different nginx_location?"

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to setup an nginx server for a webservice. There are two locations for which I would need to point to the same endpoint.

The locations are specified in nginx.conf and all the endpoints are configured.

I did try using a regex pattern in nginx.conf. But that doesn't work for me.
Additionally if I keep the two locations, only one endpoint is working. When firing api request to the other endpoint, it throws 502 bad gateway.

```
        location /v1/test {
            proxy_pass http://www.testservice.com;
        }
        location /v1/tests {
            proxy_pass http://www.testservice.com;
        }
```

The test and tests locations are pointing to the same proxy_pass endpoint. However, only one of them gets served. The other throws 502 bad gateway error.

I'm trying to have the response same for both the endpoint.

Comment: The second `location` block is redundant, but should still work. Is the 502 coming from Nginx or the upstream server? Check the Nginx error log.

Comment: Its coming from nginx. Is there a way by which I can have my service serve both test and tests endpoint?

Comment: I also tried the below:
`
        location /v1/(test|tests) {
            proxy_pass http://www.testservice.com;
        }
`

Comment: The nginx log shows:
`[error] 12#12: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/v1/tests/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), `